# WP taxonomy rewrite - prepend slug based on post type name

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to dynamically prepend a taxonomy slug based on the post type that is currently being viewed?

I currently have a taxonomy that I am rewriting the slug so that the taxonomy is prepended as below:

```
$labels = array(
    "name" => __( "Locations", "" ),
    "singular_name" => __( "Location", "" ),
);

$args = array(
    "label" => __( "Locations", "" ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "public" => true,
    "hierarchical" => true,
    "label" => "Locations",
    "meta_box_cb" => false,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
    "query_var" => true,
    "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'property-sales/location', 'with_front' => true,  'hierarchical' => true, ),
    "show_admin_column" => false,
    "show_in_rest" => false,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "show_in_quick_edit" => true,
);
register_taxonomy( "location", array( "property_sales" ), $args );
```

This works fine but what if I need to also have the taxonomy available on and the slug prepended by the property_rentals post type (property-rentals slug)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `property-sales/` from the rewrite argument.

```
"rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'location', 'with_front' => true,  'hierarchical' => true, ),
```

Add `property_rentals` to the object type array.

```
register_taxonomy( "location", array( "property_sales", "property_rentals" ), $args );
```

Comment: ..actually this didn't work. Once my rewrites were flushed all links are now example.com/location/ instead of example.com/property-sales/location/ .